# PowerShell opens excel while running script and crashes

Tags: excel, powershell

I have made some code to run a Macro on 560 Excel files.

There is a small issue with the code, it seems it doesn't save excel file, and opens every excel file, cause excel to crash.

is there a way to have the macro be ran on these 560 files in the backround, and to automatically save once macro is ran, rather than saving it manually?

Thanks

Here is my Code:

```
# start excel
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application

# get files
$files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\ME\Desktop\TEST'

# loop through all files in the directory
ForEach ($file in $files){

    # open the file
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file.FullName)

    # make file visible
    $excel.Visible = $true

    # run macro
    $app = $excel.Application
    $app.run("PERSONAL.xlsb!Module6.MyMacro")
}
```

Comment: Does it work at the first run ? COM object can be tricky and crash after the first run if you don't end the COM object instance. Plus, you can the save a workbook this way `$workbook.SaveAs($file)`

Answer (score 0):

By setting `$excel.Visible = $true`, the code will become much slower because of all the screen updates involved.

Also, you do not save the workbook after running the code, and because you never quit Excel and remove the COM objects from memory, eventually it will crash because of running out of resources.

Try:

```
# start excel
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

# get files and loop through the list
# the usual extension for macro-enabled Excel files is `*.xlsm`.
# if your files have this extension, add -Filter '*.xlsm' to the 
# Get-ChildItem command below.
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\ME\Desktop\TEST' -File | ForEach-Object {
    # open the file
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($_.FullName)

    # run macro
    $app = $excel.Application
    $app.run("PERSONAL.xlsb!Module6.MyMacro")
    $workbook.Close($true)  # $true --> save changes
}

$excel.Quit()

# cleanup COM objects
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```